# Android activity won't start consistently when called in service onTaskRemoved

Tags: android, android-activity, android-service, kill-process

On my Samsung S9 with Android 8.1 (Oreo). I am trying to start an activity on my service's onTaskRemoved(), so I can reinitialize my notifications (WorkManager) and prevent the app from force closing (saw this solution somewhere on Stack Overflow but don't remember where :(, sorry). The code would occasionally work (the application does not disconnect from Android studio, and scheduled notifications are successfully received on time). However, the activity usually does not start. I tried, with no avail, to put startActivity() in a loop to retry upon failure. Why is the activity not starting?

I know for sure that both the service and activities are properly registered in the AndroidManifest. In addition, I know that onCreate is not being called in the activity, because the logger message in the onCreate is not printing.

````
    public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent) {
        Log.d("Logtag", "Application has been closed by user");

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, LaunchActivity.class);
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_LAUNCHED_FROM_HISTORY);
        this.startActivity(intent);
    }```
````

Comment: did you try to get the application context instead of using the service context ?

Comment: Yeah, I tried using application context and various contexts derived from my activities, but none of them worked :(

Comment: is your target version is android Q (10)?

Comment: No, my target version is API 27. I'll try setting it to Q tomorrow morning and will tell you how it goes. Thanks

Comment: Anytime, I asked you about the target version as in android Q it's not permitted to run any activity from background anymore, tell me also about the android version device you are testing on

Comment: I updated to Android Q, and you're right about the inability to start activities from the background. Unfortunately, that means I still don't have a way of ensuring WorkManager delivers when the application is swiped away from recents. ;( Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, I just don't want you to get disappointed, can you tell me the use case and what you want to accomplish? maybe I could help you with another way.
And one last thing from User Experience perspective it's not a good thing to force open your app when the user intended to stop it

Comment: I was trying to use WorkManager to deliver notifications, but they stopped working when the app was swiped from recents. I posted another thread here with more details: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57640839/notifications-not-running-when-is-app-is-swiped-from-recents-samsung-s9-running  Any help would be appreciated :)